# Scala IDE + Play Framework - no breakpoint hit

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework-2.0

I ran the Play Framework website using "activator -jvm-debug 9999 ~run" command as stated in the documentation and used "Remote Java Application" debug configuration in Scala IDE. From the Debug perspective, it looks it's connected.

However no breakpoint is ever hit. Is there a way to fix it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it didn't work was hidden in the build.sbt, the fork in run was set to true.

With setting

```
fork in run := false
```

the debugger works.

Answer (score 0):

1st I would recommend to use simply sbt: `sbt -jvm-debug 9999 run`

2nd, you need to connect the scala IDE to the jvm process (never did in Scala IDE, just Intellij, but found [this docs](http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/features/scaladebugger/index.html))

finally, there are some (rare) problems in more complex scala lines of code. Try to set the breakpoint in more simple lines (declarations of values for instance)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately it didn't work. I tried the sbt command and putting the breakpoints into the most simple places as well as different settings of remote debugger. Neither helped.